# How to attach CSS file to xml file format?

Tags: css, xml

This is my first xml file testing with a css file. I was following a tutorial on youtube. There was one difference between output I got and the output in the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aG9dx1e5bVk&list=UU9sv4Vo3lK3pYzrRvDujYbw)

When this guys is creating a xml file which is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<first>
    This is first XML here
</first>
```

and open this file in browser, he gets content which is

```
<first>
    This is first XML here
</first>
```

but when I did same thing I got this in the browser

```
This is first XML here
```

I ignored this difference and then I added css file:

I created a style.css file in same folder:

```
first
(
    display : block;
    font-family : Arial;
    font-size : large;
    color : Blue;
)
```

And then I changed xml file to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css"?>
<first>
    This is first XML here
</first>
```

but output in the browser is same as before. It seems css does not changing anything. I am using Xmplify XML Editor on Mac OS and also I used Safari and google chrome for the output but neither of them worked. I appreciate if anyone can help me with that.

Comment: @torazaburo I know very basic can you explain your comment in an answer. Do you mean tutorial is wrong or old? What is the solution?

Comment: @torazaburo here also they used '<?xml-stylesheet' with css : http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_display.asp

Comment: Run your CSS file through a CSS linter.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a little change from

first
(
    display : block;
    font-family : Arial;
    font-size : large;
    color : Blue;
)

To

```
first
{
    display : block;
    font-family : Arial;
    font-size : large;
    color : Blue;
}
```

But in the video he used first style and I am not sure why did not work for me but with second one it worked

Comment: No, he did not use the first style in the video. It's invalid CSS. By the way, this is not really an "answer" to your question. It's you finding your own typo. Probably best just to close the question.